# When Decrementing by 1, Unity decrements by a random number

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an FPS game in Unity and have setup a RayCast shooting system. Whenever I shoot, I have it set where the gun ammo count should decrement by 1. However, every time I left-click it decrements the ammo count by a random number and I have no idea why. The counter decreases by 8, by 12, by 10, 9, just random integers. It should only be decreasing by 1 right?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int id;
    float nextTimeToFire;
    
    [SerializeField] int currAmmo;
    float reloadSpeed = 1;
    
    public GameObject gameController;
    public ItemDatabase database;
    
    public Camera mainCam;
    
    void Start()
    {
        gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("GameController");
        database = gameController.GetComponent<ItemDatabase> ();
        mainCam = Camera.main;
        id = GetComponent<ItemID> ().itemID;
        
        currAmmo = database.weapons[id].maxAmmo;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {   
        if(currAmmo <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
            return;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    
    }
    
    void Shoot()
    {
        currAmmo--;
        
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(mainCam.transform.position, mainCam.transform.forward, out hit, database.weapons [id].range))
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f/database.weapons [id].fireRate;
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                Debug.Log (hit.transform.name);             
                CharacterStats enemyStats = hit.transform.GetComponent<CharacterStats> ();
                enemyStats.TakeDamage (database.weapons [id].damage);
                Debug.Log (database.weapons [id].damage);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (reloadSpeed);
        
        currAmmo = database.weapons [id].maxAmmo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You check if the button is down. The first thing you need to do is reset timetofire as it will keep doing it each frame

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you showing the ammo count from a database. The code here should decrease the index by 1 so did you check the database indexes. It may be the issue that the ammo count in the database is out of order. My opinion though...